# Linkedin API '/rest/posts' doesn't return all posts it should: some posts stay unseen

Tags: linkedin-api, zapier

I use Zapier to regularly get last posts of my company page on Linkedin using the rest API but some posts are not seen. To be more precise, when I ask for the last 10 posts, I only get 8, and all of them are well within the last 10 posts. In other words, the api seems to see the 2 missing posts and count them among the 10, but does not return their content.

I use the following url :
`https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts?q=author&author={organization urn}&isDsc=false&count=10`

Linkedin documentation : *https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/posts-api*

I can't find anything particular for these posts, so I don't get why the request skips them. Does anyone has an idea about it ?

Comment: https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts?q=author&author=urn:li:person:vO2dw56SKV&isDsc=false&count=10, can you tell me what is wrong with this syntax to get posts of a given linkedin user.it is is saying "Invalid query parameters passed to request"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue myself.

Changing the value of the `isDsc` parameter to `true` fixed the problem for me. Well, it's not really a fix, but it seems like LinkedIn is just hiding Dsc posts rather than not returning them at all.

Comment: well it seems we actually need to do both true and false to get all of them

but even like this I am still missing some posts

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently having the same issue where I can't retrieve posts in a `DRAFT` state.

In the docs, it mentions to include a `viewContext` parameter with the value of `AUTHOR` to retrieve posts not in a `PUBLISHED` state, but it still doesn't seem to be working - but maybe this will solve the issue for you?

*Update: Nevermind - I just re-read the docs and this looks to only be applicable to retrieving posts by their URN.*